# define constructor function in a sub function of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

when i want to define constructor function as   property of my object in sub function it's shows fallowing error when i call constructor function:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'arr[0].myval()')
```

i define my object like below code's

```
function stocks(nemad,url,content) {
    this.url=url;
    this.nemad=nemad;
    this.content=content;
    var me=this;
    nemad = require('webpage').create();
    nemad.open(url, function (status) {
        this.myval=function () {
            return nemad.evaluate(function() {
                var myans=document.getElementById("d12").innerHTML;
                return myans;
            }); };
    }); };
```

when i call `console.log("it's :"+arr[0].myval());`it's not working .. where i make mistake

Comment: Where do you create `arr` and how, where do you call that? Notice that `open()` is async as far as I recall

Answer (score 0):

You've made a correct closure, but never use it:

```
var me = this;
...
nemad.open(url, function (status) {
   me.myval = function () {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that , we can after load a nemad ( a web page object in phantomjs for example) web can define a function with nemad evaluating codes . like below code.

```
nemad.onLoadFinished = function() {
    // here you can call a function that evaluating  nemad
   };
```

a must important point is that you can call evaluating  after page load complete